# Repaint/update a baseadapter?

Tags: android, listview, repaint, baseadapter

I'm doing an application where I need to have a listview where each row has some text and an imagebutton (just for delete that row with the same image in every button). Surfing on the net I have got this code http://www.codemobiles.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=876. Because of this code has also an image, I deleted the code for the image. All is working well but I'm trying to do the list dinamically and I can't. I have created an arraylist and modified that code to being able for adding my arraylist so now I can add or delete items (and that piece works because I have tried to run only this part of code) but I'm unable to "repaint". My idea was if I have this adapter and works, let's add or delete an item and recall the method but if I create again a caller to the creator as you can see onCreate method:

```
adap = new EfficientAdapter(this);
setListAdapter(adap);
```

There's no error but there's no news. How can I do it? Also I noticed that if I have 0 rows for not having an error in the

```
public Object getItem(int position)
```

I return an empty string array and in this method:

```
public int getCount()
```

I return 0 but then I have a row. how can I fix that?

My code for this 2 methods are:

```
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    // My arraylist is data2. Because of I didn't know how to do 
//an arraylist of n elements with 3 subelements in each element and then convert
// it to an array, I add every subelement one after one and then I don't mix subelements.
        String [] cambio = (String[]) data2.toArray(new String[data2.size()]);
        if (cambio.length == 0){
            return 0;
        }
        String[] cambio2 = new String[cambio.length/3];
        int j = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<(cambio.length/3);i=i+3){
                   //that's because I need an output of a single string array and
// I need my subelements in this order
            cambio2[j] = cambio[i+1] + " " + cambio[i+2] + "  " +  cambio[i];
            j++;
        }           
        return cambio2.length;
        //return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String [] cambio = (String[]) data2.toArray(new String[data2.size()]);
        if (cambio.length == 0){
            return cambio;
        }
        String[] cambio2 = new String[cambio.length/3];
        int j = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<(cambio.length/3);i=i+3){
            cambio2[j] = cambio[i+1] + " " + cambio[i+2] + "  " +  cambio[i];
            j++;
        }
        return cambio2[position];
        //return data[position];
    }
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: just add    adap.notifyDataSetChanged();